# Производное и производящее слово

Tags: словообразование

Производящее и производное слова объединены правильно в парах:
1)  богатый → разбогатеть
2)  жизнь → жизненный
3)  цвет → бесцветный
4)  ежиха→ ежонок
5)  валить → развалиться

Comment: у меня большое сомнение в 4) и отчасти в 5). А как вообще условие было сформулировано? Слова были заданы в условии или вы придумали сами?

Comment: точно также, как я написал

Comment: Т.е. это домашнее задание?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) богатый → богатеть - разбогатеть

2) жизнь → жизненный

3) цвет → бесцветный

4) еж→ ежонок

5) валить → развалить - развалиться

Comment: Vera,  вы напрасно приучаете двоечников к получению бесплатных ответов на этом ресурсе.

Comment: Но ответы же были даны, надо было только проверить их правильность.

Comment: Так он же сказал, что это не ответы, а условие задания. И потом. Вы серьезно думаете, что учащийся сам придумал вариант "ежиха" - "ежонок"? Это их проверяют так на соображалку.